# How do I get Ranger to open HTML files in Google Chrome instead of Firefox?

Tags: linux

I'm using Ranger as my default file manager on Linux Mint. I can't figure out how to make Ranger open HTML files in Google Chrome.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/1160955/180675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the example rifle.conf

```
gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/ranger/config/rifle.conf.gz > .config/ranger/rifle.conf
```

And add `ext x?html?, has google-chrome,  X, flag f = google-chrome -- "$@"`

 above line 57

If you want to open a new window everytime, add --new-window to the command

[image: Ranger config]

Comment: You can also just try to use the **r** key, where you can select the program you want to open with. See https://superuser.com/a/1330354/180675

Answer (score 0):

Press `r`

```
0 | firefox -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
1 | chromium -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2 | google-chrome -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
3 | w3m "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
4 | ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                
5 | "$PAGER" -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
6 | xdg-open -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
8 | mkdir -p -- ${XDG_DATA_DIR:-$HOME/.ranger}/ranger-trash; mv -- "$@" ${XDG_DATA_DIR:-$HOME/.ranger}/ranger-trash
```

:open_with `vim`

Instead type a number I typed vim, and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As a simpler alternative solution, execute:

```
$ ranger --copy-config rifle
```

then edit `~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf` and just comment out the line containing Firefox option:

```
ext x?html?, has opera,            X, flag f = opera -- "$@"
#ext x?html?, has firefox,          X, flag f = firefox -- "$@"
ext x?html?, has seamonkey,        X, flag f = seamonkey -- "$@"
```